# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'contactId' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

On my model (`Customer`) I have one required parameter: `$contactId`.

On executing `Customer::create(['contactId' => $contactId])` I receive the following error:

> "message": "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'contactId' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `customers` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2019-12-10 12:33:46, 2019-12-10 12:33:46))"

The contactId field is nowhere to be found on in the insert statement. The value of `contactId` is set to `4`, which corresponds to the correct value in the database through a `FK`.

The migration for the `Customer` table:

```sql
`Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
            $table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
            $table->bigInteger('contactId')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('contactId', 'FK_customer_contactId_contact_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('contacts');
        });`
```

What's preventing `Eloquent` from creating the correct insert statement here? I've triple checked the spelling of `contactId` throughout the flow and in the database.

When I manually insert a row into `customers`, I have no issues retrieving the data and the `contact`-relation.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Is `$contactId` a null value?

Comment: @JeremyHarris it's not nullable. It turns out I didn't fully understand the workings of $fillable. Dilip his answer is the correct solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make contactId `$fillable` in `Customer` model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['contactId'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**If you use `create` method to save data in to database so you must have to write this `fillable` property in your model**

```
<?php

class Customer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['contactId'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make contactId $fillable in model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['contactId'];
}
```

or

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```